# which class lauches Android main launcher activity

Tags: android, program-entry-point, android-launcher

can anyone pls tell ,which class in **android** launches the **main launcher** **activity** as soon as we click on application icon?
any help  will  be appreciated

Comment: Application icon is displayed by Launcher.apk so you need to see code of that application in AOSP android source code or in other available launcher apk code

Answer (score 0):

The class having below `intent-filter` inside Application Manifest file

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

For more information read official document [Starting An Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file your all activities defines Like

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_A">
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".Activity_B">
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".Activity_C">
        </activity>
```

If i want to Activity B is launcher activity simply i am paste the intent filter inside the Activity B Like

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity_B">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Specifies the types of intents that an activity, service, or broadcast receiver can respond to. An intent filter declares the capabilities of its parent component — what an activity or service can do and what types of broadcasts a receiver can handle. It opens the component to receiving intents of the advertised type, while filtering out those that are not meaningful for the component.
Most of the contents of the filter are described by its action, category, and data subelements. for more detail please see the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

Very first time load Application class

```
   class MyApplication extends Application {
    }
```

After loading  LauncherActivity ("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" )

```
   class MainActivity  extends Activity {
    }

 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```